# How to get this string (html tag) with regex?

Tags: php, regex, simple-html-dom

i have string **(not html tag)**

e.g :

```
<div class="lh">
    <b>Review: <b>Sarah Geronimo</b> leaves UAE fans asking for more</b></a><br>
    <font size="-1"><b><font color="#6f6f6f">gulfnews.com</font></b></font><br>
    <font size="-1"><b>Geronimo</b> how to get this contents <b>...</b></font><br>
    <font size="-1" class="p"></font><br><font class="p" size="-1"><nobr><b>and more&nbsp;»</b></nobr></a></font>
</div>
```

i want get strings **"how to get this contents"** . how i do that with regex ?

**UPDATE**

in this case why do I use regex? because results it contains html tags

I'm parsing this site https://news.google.com/news/feeds?q=sarah%20geronimo%20&output=rss

this all my code :

```
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html = file_get_html("https://news.google.com/news/feeds?q=sarah%20geronimo%20&output=rss");

foreach($html->find('item') as $item) {
    $items['desc'] = $item->find('description',0)->plaintext;   
    $data[] = $items;
}

$regex = '~(?s)<div[^>]*>(?:.*?<font size){2}[^>]*><b>.*?</b>\K[^<]+~';

foreach($data as $content) {
        $desc = $content['desc'];
        preg_match($regex,$desc ,$m);
        echo $m[0];
}
```

i want get content in tag `<description>`. which the content containing html tag and i'm using regex to remove it

but its return blank ?

Comment: Really sure you want to use a regex for that and not a DOM parser?

Comment: yes, for this case i need regex not DOM parser

Comment: For what reason are you not using a DOM parser? [You really should consider it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1594318).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php)

Comment: look at my update question

Comment: [Obligatory link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4231382/471272).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this regex:

```
(?s)<div[^>]*>(?:.*?<font size){2}[^>]*><b>.*?</b>\K[^<]+
```

**How to use it:**

```
$str = '<div class="lh">
    <b>Review: <b>Sarah Geronimo</b> leaves UAE fans asking for more</b></a><br>
    <font size="-1"><b><font color="#6f6f6f">gulfnews.com</font></b></font><br>
    <font size="-1"><b>Geronimo</b> how to get this contents <b>...</b></font><br>
    <font size="-1" class="p"></font><br><font class="p" size="-1"><nobr><b>and more&nbsp;»</b></nobr></a></font>
</div>';

$regex = '~(?s)<div[^>]*>(?:.*?<font size){2}[^>]*><b>.*?</b>\K[^<]+~';

if(preg_match($regex,$str,$m)) {
    echo $m[0]."<br />";
}
```

**Output:**

```
how to get this contents
```

Let me know if you have any questions. :)

Comment: @Chielarck Did this help, or are you still having a problem with the question?

Comment: thanks, regex code it's work . but not for my case. look at my Update question